# AutoHotkey: Test if a string is a URL

Tags: url, substring, autohotkey

Ok, so I've got this AutoHotkey snippet:

```
; Google text from any app
; from http://superuser.com/questions/7271/most-useful-autohotkey-scripts/165220#165220
#s::
MyClip := ClipboardAll
clipboard = ; empty the clipboard
Send, ^c
ClipWait, 2
if ErrorLevel  ; ClipWait timed out.
    return
Run http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=%clipboard%
Clipboard := MyClip
```

It works fine, but I'd like to improve it to handle the case where you highlight a URL and automatically run the URL itself (`Run %clipboard%`) instead of searching Google for it.  How can I get AutoHotkey to detect if a string is a URL?

Seems like I could use `StringLeft` or `SubStr` to extract the first few characters and see if they match `http://` or `www.`, or maybe something more robust using regular expressions?  I don't really understand AHK's syntax, though.

[This script](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/UrlHistory/UrlHistory.ahk) checks the clipboard for URLs, apparently using `StringGetPos`, but I don't want to detect if www appears *anywhere* in the string.  Only if it appears at the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your script with code to check if the copied text is a URL via a regular expression. If it's a URL it just runs the text, otherwise it uses the old behaviour of searching Google for the copied text.

```
#s::
MyClip := ClipboardAll
clipboard = ; empty the clipboard
Send, ^c
ClipWait, 2
if ErrorLevel  ; ClipWait timed out.
    return
If RegExMatch(Clipboard, "^(https?://|www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$")
    Run %Clipboard%
Else
    Run http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=%clipboard%
Clipboard := MyClip
```

**Edit:** Changed code to also match web addresses starting with just 'www'.

Comment: Great!  I also wanted it to handle "www.something.com" though.  The Run command works with these

Comment: Sorry, I missed that bit in your question. I've edited the code to also work with URLs that start with 'www' and not 'http://'.

Comment: Great! I also added URI encoding to it, so it can handle searching for  things like "#IfWinActive".  https://gist.github.com/823381